# Could not parse text error in sheet from double quotes in attachment

Tags: regex, parsing, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am running an app script in sheets, which usually brings in an attachment from Gmail into google sheets. It works most of the time, but when data contains double quotes it is generating a parse error

my source data is thousands of rows like this:

```
",05/02/2019,3:13,151:22,5:30,08:11,Enroute,C000003251,219688X01232019,BIN11,,Item1,08:11,0:05,,,0:00
Worker2,34:51,869:25,110:00,"Completed: 168
Suspended: 43
Skipped: 41
",05/02/2019,3:13,151:22,5:30,08:17,OnSite,C000003251,219688X01232019,BIN11,,Item1,,,08:17,0:16,0:30
Worker2,34:51,869:25,110:00,"Completed: 168
Suspended: 43
Skipped: 41
",05/02/2019,3:13,151:22,5:30,08:34,Complete,C000003251,219688X01232019,BIN11,,Item1,,,,,0:00
Worker2,34:51,869:25,110:00,"Completed: 168
Suspended: 43
Skipped: 41
",05/02/2019,3:13,151:22,5:30,08:42,Enroute,C000003252,219689X01232019,BIN11,,Item1,08:42,0:00,,,0:00
Worker2,34:51,869:25,110:00,"Completed: 168
Suspended: 43
Skipped: 41
",05/02/2019,3:13,151:22,5:30,08:42,OnSite,C000003252,219689X01232019,BIN11,,Item1,,,08:42,0:14,0:30
Worker2,34:51,869:25,110:00,"Completed: 168
Suspended: 43
Skipped: 41
",05/02/2019,3:13,151:22,5:30,08:56,Complete,C000003252,219689X01232019,BIN11,,Item1,,,,,0:00
Worker2,34:51,869:25,110:00,"Completed: 168
Suspended: 43
Skipped: 41
",05/02/2019,3:13,151:22,5:30,08:57,Enroute,C000003253,219690X01232019,BIN11,,Item1,08:57,0:05,,,0:00
```

---

```
  attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();  
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

    var sheet =   
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Month1");
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ","); 

    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, 

csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

I am getting this error: "Could not parse text" I can't seem to figure out how to either ignore or remove the double quotes in the source data

thanks in advance!

Comment: When your CSV sample in your question is used for ``Utilities.parseCsv()``, no error occurs. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So can you provide the detail information for replicating your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue seems to have resolved itself

Answer (score 0):

you can use either of these formulas to remove all double quotes from your dataset

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, """", ""))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, """", ""))
```

or if that is the option you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and remove them entirely.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, this is an app script which runs on a timer, and is used to push data to other applications. This is not something that interacted with manually.